# Javascript doesnt seem to be attachet to my jsp

Tags: javascript

When i load login.jsp it doesn't alert if i dont input password or username 
tried checking wether i correctly attached the file but it still doesnt work for me, what could be the reason?jsp just reacts the way it would react if i wouldn't use js at all

LoginPage.js

```
function check()
{ 

     var username = document.form.username.value; 
     var password = document.form.password.value;


     if (username==null || username=="")
     { 
     alert("Username can't be blank"); 
     return false; 
     }
     else if(password==null||password=="")
     { 
     alert("Password must be inserted "); 
     return false; 
     } 

 }
```

my jsp:

```
<body>



            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="get" action="LoginServlet" onsubmit="return check()">
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username">

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="login-button" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" >
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Don't have an account?<a href="register.jsp">Sign Up</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="LoginPage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly check the HTML syntax of your jsp, it seems that the html is broken because of the last three `</div>` because of the missing opening tags.

Then, you don't have by default a `document.form` property so you could get your username and password in the following way:

```
// or you can use document.getElementById('username')
const username = document.querySelector('#username').value; 
const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
```

[here details about the `querySelector` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)